# Не удается построить boost

Tags: mingw, boost, build, c++

При попытке откомпилить либы такой вот командой

```
bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=c:\mingw\include\boost\install" install
```

пишет:

```
C:\MinGW\include\boost\boost_1_47_0>bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=c:\mingw\include\boost\install" install
warning: mismatched versions of Boost.Build engine and core
warning: Boost.Build engine (bjam) is 03.1.18
warning: Boost.Build core (at C:/MinGW/include/boost/boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2) is 2011.04-svn
C:/MinGW/include/boost/boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/tools\gcc.jam:129: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: no command provided, default command 'g++' not found
error: initialized from
C:/MinGW/include/boost/boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/build\toolset.jam:38: in toolset.using from mod
ule toolset
C:/MinGW/include/boost/boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:481: in process-explicit-tools
et-requests from module build-system
C:/MinGW/include/boost/boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:562: in load from module build
-system
C:\MinGW\include\boost\boost_1_47_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import from module m
odules
C:\MinGW\include\boost\boost_1_47_0\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from m
odule
C:\MinGW\include\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

Я уже и тулзы пытался ребилдить, и что только не это а результат всегда один и тот же.

Comment: Не соответствуют друг другу версии bjam и Boost.Build core (правда предупреждение, но ежели не идёт, то лучше нафиг). А с предыдущими (или стабильными) версиями всё нормально? А то, что компилятора в обозримых окрестностях нет -- это нормально (default command 'g++' not found)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот главная ошибка: `no command provided, default command 'g++' not found`.

Попробуйте из `MSYS / cmd` запустить `g++`, если не получится, то необходимо его доустановить *(например, через `mingw-get`).*